# Does every imeOptions value have a default behavior besides closing the keyboard?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, imeoptions

Some  of the `EditText`'s `android:imeOptions` values have a default behavior: `actionNext` jumps to the next input field, `actionDone` closes the soft keyboard and so on.
I know how to override the click behavior in Java, but I wonder if values like `actionSearch` have some sort of default behavior besides closing the keyboard, or is that attribute mainly there to change the icon of the action button?

Comment: That one is there to change the icon.  While there is a search interface in Android, its a moderate amount of code to implement that wouldn't be possible by the framwork without help in its current state.

Comment: Ok thank you. So it is mainly about the icon? I say mainly because it has some default behavior (like closing the keyboard, or changing focus for other imeOption values)